# “I beg pardon” vs. “I beg your pardon”

Tags: grammaticality, difference

I read something said here recently and the person said **“I beg pardon”**.

I often hear **“I beg your pardon”**.

So between the two, which is correct?

Comment: Both are in use.

Comment: Thanks so much StoneyB. Pls can you explain more extensively. Can they be used in the same context?

Comment: I don't hear either one of them used very often nowadays, but I'd guess the four-word version is more common.

Comment: They are both used to express, courteously, your failure to understand, as is the even shorter version "Beg pardon?" They are generally spoken with the stress on PAR and a rising, question intonation on the final syllable. "I BEG your PARdon" is used, with the indicated stressses and a falling tone on the final syllable, to express a apology, real or feigned.

Comment: [Here's a graph](http://goo.gl/MNbJs0) to support @J.R.'s sense of things. It does seem like the phrase—with the inclusion of “your”—is making a comeback.

Comment: @Tyler - We have to be careful presuming a blip like that means a phrase is "making a comeback." Remember where that data comes from: published books. It may not be the _phrase_ that's making a comeback, but some classic books. I looked at Google books where the phrase was used between [2005-2008](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%20beg%20your%20pardon%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2005,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en). On the first page of results, there were works by Chesterton, Thackery, Dostoevsky, Dickens, W. Collins and Jane Austen: all published since 2005 – but written around a century ago.

Comment: @J.R. Fair enough. I hear the phrase (with “your”) from time to time, though.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung - _I beg your pardon?_ ;^)

Answer (score 2):

As StoneyB comments, both are in use. But note that the *"your"* version has become far more common over the past couple of centuries, so you should use that if you want to sound "natural" today...

[image]

Having said that, even *"I beg **your** pardon"* is a relatively dated/starchy/formal usage today for many people. When it *is* used, it's normally in one of three contexts (most common first)...

> 1: *"I didn't catch what you just said (can you repeat it please?"*
>   2: *"I'm shocked by what you just said"* (often, with exaggerated stress on ***beg***)
>    3: *"Please forgive/excuse me"* (a more "literal" usage)

Obviously there are many different ways to express each of those senses. See [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3232/how-do-you-decide-which-phrase-to-use-when-asking-people-to-repeat-what-they-sai) for a list of alternatives to #1 above (where you'll see *"I beg your pardon"* is classed as the *most* formal).